# React-select {creatable} to work with user typed entry as only shows no options

Tags: javascript, react-select

Issue with react-select CreatableSelect not allowing create

I have made the attached component for a bootstrap table. I can see my hard coded labels the same way I would using Select however I can not get the Creatable part working for the user to enter a new option. I just get the label No options.

I have tried to get the new input added to cars array and print to console but cannot figure it out.

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select';

const cars = [
  { label: "audi", value: 1 },
  { label: "bmw", value: 2 },
  { label: "ford", value: 3 },
  { label: "VW", value: 4 },
];

const selectOption = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="container">
      <CreatableSelect
         options={cars} 
         placeholder={"check and enter new car name here"}
         isClearable
         onChange={(opt, meta) => console.log(opt, meta)}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default selectOption
```

I would like it to show the create option when typing an option not in the dropdown list and add it to the cars array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns out that i have this:

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select';
```

and i needed this:

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
```

all works now!
thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `this.state.cars={initialCarOption}` in `Constructor`. Then, you need to do following in `render` method:

```
return (
      <CreatableSelect
        options={this.state.cars}
        placeholder={"check and enter new car name here"}
        isClearable
        onChange={(opt, meta) =>
          this.setState({ cars: this.state.cars.slice().concat(opt) })
        }
      />
    );
```

This way, when user enters a new value, that value will be added to `this.state.cars` and it will be visible in `options` dropdown via `options={this.state.cars}`.

You can look at sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-2rbl7. In the sandbox, once you add a value, it will be added at the end in the `options` array.